# Chinese seal identification

Tags: translation

[image]

[image]

Please help me identify the calligraphy and seal on this silk painting

Answer (score 2):

From right to left

花香鳥語 (Flower's Fragrance, birds' songs)

庚子歳 仲春 in the middle of Spring in the year of [庚子](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%BA%9A%E5%AD%90/599508)

*"歳" means "year"(年); "仲" means "middle of"; "春" means "Spring"*

*The last 庚子年 was **1960**; the next 庚子年 is 2020*

志航寫 = wrote by Zhi Hang (志航 is the author)

Answer (score 1):

> 花香鳥語

*Fragrance of flowers and chirping of birds* (= Springtime)

> 庚子籤仲春

*Marked on the second month of the spring season on the year of* [庚子](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BA%9A%E5%AD%90). Not sure of 籤 (*marked/labelled*).

> 志航寫

*Written by* 志航

> 志航

(Seal)

Comment: As Tang Ho suggests the uncertain character should be 岁, i think.

Comment: @Vim as much as I want to believe this, I do not find that shape convincing as 歳

Comment: 歳 make perfect sense in this context.. The top is clearly 山,  lower left stroke of 示 cross over with the  lower left stroke of 厂.  It is  歳 no doubt. If you say it is 籤 , first it make no sense, second, it missed the bottom stroke

Comment: @TangHo I’m not sure that I agree with any of  that comment. The top doesn’t look like 山 at all, the bottom left is super wonky (歲 has a very clean bottom left edge). As for 籖 not making sense, maybe or maybe not.